# Trying to get textbox to align next to text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="currency-contanier">
   <div class="col-md-6">12</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
        <input class="form-control valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CADDay must be a number." data-val-required="The CADDay field is required." id="CADDay" name="CADDay" type="text" value="12" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="CADDay-error">
   </div>
</div>
```

And the css...

```
.currency-contanier {
    height: 90px;
    line-height: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
}
```

On my dev box, it looks like this:

[image]

I'd like them both to be centered in both directions.. or in other words, move the textbox down so it's next to the text.

Comment: are `col-md-*`classes supposed to mean you're using bootstrap? Because there's not css library imported in the fiddle.

Comment: ah, good point.  BRB

Comment: argh... don't know fiddle very well.  Trying to recall how to import Bootstrap...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `input` element `inline` and limit its `width`:

```
.currency-contanier input {
  display: inline;
  width: 3em;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyrRqE

Comment: that did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML Structure is missing the container and row classes and divs respectively:

```
<div class="contanier">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="currency-contanier">
         <div class="col-md-6">12</div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
               <input class="form-control valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CADDay must be a number." data-val-required="The CADDay field is required." id="CADDay" name="CADDay" type="text" value="12" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="CADDay-error">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Also you only need to add: `display:inline-block;` to the input and it will sit next to the 12. No need to declare a width as it is using bootstraps form control class which gives the input `width:100%;` relative to its parent container.

Comment: Ok, thanks! What I didn't mention is that this is inside a <td>.  In that case, would I still need the div for container and row?

Comment: You should use the container div to wrap the table in and then add bootstraps `.table` class to the table to make it responsive.

Comment: Yeah, did that already.  I just didn't think I needed all that for this one snippet where I was having the trouble.